# Don't send daily Local Notification if app already opened

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, uilocalnotification

I'm sending a `Local Notification` every day at the same time.

I was wondering if there were a way to **not send the notification if the user had already opened the app that day**?

*Here's the code I'm using to check if notifications are allowed, and then send the notification:*

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;
    UIUserNotificationSettings *mySettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:mySettings];

    // before we create any new ones, cancel all existing notifications
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]cancelAllLocalNotifications];

    if ([[[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings] types] != UIUserNotificationTypeNone) {

        UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

        NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
        NSDateComponents *comp = [cal components:(NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
        comp.hour = 19; // 19 = 7PM
        comp.minute = 45; // 7:45 PM
        comp.second = 01; // 7:45:01 PM

        localNotification.fireDate = [cal dateFromComponents:comp];
        localNotification.alertBody = @"Local Notification in iOS8";
        localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitDay;

        // this will schedule the notification to fire at the fire date
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
        // this will fire the notification right away, it will still also fire at the date we set
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:localNotification];

    }
}
```

Edit: Here's the code I'm trying to implement the method suggestion per the answer below with?  I'm obviously not getting something right here though :/

```
- (void)isDateLowerThanToday {
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    int daysToAdd = -1;
    NSDate *newDate1 = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*daysToAdd];
    NSLog(@"NewDate1 = %@", newDate1);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store on [`NSUserDefaults`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html) the last notification sent date. Then, when app opens you check this value, if it's null or lower than Today you send the notification and updates the value on `NSUserDefaults` with current date.

Something like this should do the trick

```
NSString *key = @"LAST_NOTIFICATION_SENT_DATE";
NSDate *date = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:key];

// You have to implement isDateLowerThanToday
if (!date || [self isDateLowerThanToday:date]) { 
    [self sendNotification];
    date = [NSDate date];
    [[NUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:date forKey:key];
}
```

Here you have `isDateLowerThanToday` implementation

```
-(bool)isDateLowerThanToday:(NSDate *)date {
    NSDate * now = [NSDate date];
    NSComparisonResult result = [now compare:date];

    return result == NSOrderedDescending;
}
```

Comment: Sweet I'm going to try that, makes sense!

Comment: Is `[self sendNotification];` a placeholder for my code I already have that sends the notification?

Comment: I know I'm supposed to implement `isDateLowerThanToday`, but is the code inside of that method finding todays date?  I guess I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do that method?  Can you help me out on that real quick?  Thanks!

Comment: I added the best thing I could think of as an edit to my answer, what do you think?

Comment: @SRMR: sorry about the delay, added implementation

Comment: @SRMR: `[self sendNotification]` is indeed your logic to send notification